# Why does not this code work?

Tags: javascript

This code should work.. But it doesn't and I get an error message that says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
```

It is not the first time I've gotten this error and I still don't understand it...

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
<script src="myjavascript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Play</button>
<p id="test"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var things = ['rock','paper','scissors'];

function myFunction() {

var i = Math.floor(Math.random()*things.length));
document.getElementById("test"+(i+1)).innerHTML=things[i];
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you don't have an element `id="testN"` where N is the result of `i+1`.

Comment: getElementById("test"+(i+1)) you only have id="test"

Comment: Where are those `test1`, `test2`, `test3` elements in your DOM?

Comment: the element "test0" not exists, only "test".. and you are searching for elements with a id "test" + (i+1) ("test0", "test1", "test2"...) this is the reason

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood the ("test"+(i+1)) thing, now it works though thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you have any elements with ids like `test1`, `test2`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The element referenced by your code does not exist in the DOM:

```
document.getElementById("test"+(i+1))
```

You have in your HTML:

```
<p id="test"></p>
```

Your code is looking for "test3"

Answer (score 0):

If you want the single element to change the text, have this as your JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML=things[i];
```

If you want it go go into multiple elements, then in your HTML replace `<p id="test"></p>` with:

```
<p id="test1"></p>
<p id="test2"></p>
<p id="test3"></p>
```